# how to select from one database using codition in another

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select from one database using condition in another but my problem is how to do this in my editor i used this code in my phpmyadmin environment and it work fine, but how will write same query in my source code,my problem here is how to connect to two different db in one statement

```
  select * from users.message where sender in( select id from secured.reg_users)
```

Comment: As long as the 2 databases are in the same mysql server, the above query will work. If not, then you can experiment with federated tables, but most likely you can't do this in sql only.

Comment: if the two  database are on the same server generally   you don't need  two connection  ..  you can access both the db using a single connection

Comment: it works when i insert the code in phpmyadmin environ but i don't know how to use it in my code because i need to connect to both db i only know about connecting to one like $sql = $db1->prepare but am selecting from two db

Comment: alright thanks let me try the connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the 2 databases are in the same mysql server, the above query will work with a **single connection**. (Remember, phpmyadmin will connect to a single database as well at any point of time!) If not, then you can experiment with [federated tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/federated-storage-engine.html), but most likely you will not be able to do this in sql only.

In the latter case, your code needs to retrieve the list of ids from the `secured.reg_users` table, then use that list as parameter to the main query.